# I can't install any new python module

Tags: python, pip, python-install

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\91731\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rllib3 (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\91731\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rllib3 (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\91731\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages)WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rllib3 (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
```

here I Was just trying to install tkinter

I tried everything, I tried using virtual environment, but same issue comes,after sometimes.

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. Either way, you'll need to clean up some stray files from the directories mentioned; it's hard to say which files exactly, but I'd look for e.g. something like `~rllib3`.

Comment: It may be worth noting that Anaconda3 has tkinter installed by default.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69621610/19595194
try this link to get your answer
remove site packages folder where your python install.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [answer], and keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. If someone's question is already answered somewhere else on Stack Overflow, do not answer it, and do not use the answer section to give a link. This is because we have a system in place to take care of duplicate questions, and writing answers makes it harder to clean up questions that are no longer wanted on the site. At 15 reputation you can flag questions to bring attention to duplicates.